# Using write.xlsx to write different data on different sheets in one file by for loop in r

Tags: r, for-loop, xlsx

I am trying to write each country's data on each sheet named with that country in one `xlsx` file. I am using `xlsx` package in r.
I have tried

```
  for (i in 1:noctry) {
     write.xlsx(tab110rev[i,,], file="table.xlsx", sheetName = countrylist[i],
              col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)  
}
```

`noctry` stands for number of countries and its 53
`countrylist` is a list of countries with country codes which are numbers.
`tab110rev` is an array that has the structure of `array(value, c(country, industry, year))`

The problem with this is that it only produces a `xlsx` file with just one sheet which contains the last country. There should be 53 sheets, not just one.
I think the `for-loop` is overwriting instead of cumulating the result but I have no idea to fix this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess `append = T` should fix your problem. 
Try this:

```
for (i in 1:noctry) {
     write.xlsx(tab110rev[i,,], file="table.xlsx", sheetName = countrylist[i],
                col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, append = T)  
}
```

Comment: You are my hero... Thanks a lot!

Comment: @kim1298 No problem, people help each other here. You can mark the answer you like by clicking 'accept', so that others know issue is solved.